# Why making an empty struct a new typedef and using it as a pointer type?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have a header and a sample application using this header, all in C, I get almost all the logic of this software except for this; this the interesting part of the header:

```
struct A;
typedef struct A A;
```

in the C application this `A` is only used when declaring a pointer like this

```
A* aName;
```

I'm quite sure that this is a solution for just including `A` in the scope/namespace and give just a name to a basically void pointer, because this kind of pointer is only used to handle some kind of data, it is more like some namespace sugar.

What this could be for?

Comment: The structure `A` may be defined in another header file, and `struct A;` just declares it, telling the compiler that there is a structure named `A`.

Comment: and the typedef is only there to avoid having to write "struct" all over the place.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i'm actually using doxygen to scan all the headers and there is no other reference to this label.

Comment: @AndreasHenning i get that, the problem is that is empty.

Comment: @Ken I doubt that. wouldn't the compiler complain about that?

Comment: @AndreasHenning i'm also checking manually and there is nothing, it's an empty struct ...

Comment: @Ken If you don't have the definition of `A` anywhere then linker would have barfed about it. Dig deep, you'll find it somewhere.

Comment: the structure `A` may be a system structure, you have to check not only your own header file but all those of the system as well. And by check I mean do a proper search, not just trust the output of Doxygen.

Comment: please provide code examples of how it's used.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg but in this case why writing the first row `struct A;` ?

Comment: @KingsIndian: that's not necessarily true. In this file `A` is an incomplete type, and incomplete types are fine as long as you never dereference pointers to them (including that you can't access members of them, because of course they don't have any as far as this TU knows). No definition is needed to use it as a pointer type, and in cases where a definition is needed it'll be the compiler that barfs rather than the linker.

Comment: @SteveJessop so in your opinion my first assumption is realistic ?

Comment: @SteveJessop true, but I assumed it's *used* somewhere, not just a random declaration in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that it's like a void pointer, in that `void` is an incomplete type, and in this file `A` is also an incomplete type. About all you can do with incomplete types is pass around pointers to them.

It has one advantage over `void*` in this file, that it's a *different* and incompatible type from some other bit of code that has done the same thing with `B`. So you get a bit of type safety. If `A` is `windowHandle` and `B` is `jpgHandle`, then you can't pass the wrong one to a function.

It has an advantage over `void*` in the `.c` file that defines the functions that accept an `A*` -- that file can contain a definition of `struct A`, and give `A` whatever members it wants, that the first file doesn't need to know about.

However, you say there are no other mentions of `A` in any header file, which means there are no functions that accept or return it. You also say that the only use of `A` in your source file is to declare pointers -- I wonder where the values of those pointers come from, if any.

If all that happens if that someone defines an uninitialized `A*` and never uses it, then clearly this is a remnant of some old code, or the start of some code that never got written, and it shouldn't be in the file at all.

Finally, if the real type is called something a bit less stupid than `A`, then the name might give a clue to its use.

Comment: the problem with the clue is that the name is pretty self explanatory but there is nothing like that, no libraries or other inclusions that can remind me of that name or function, looks like something that i can't reach in any way, probably the headers are not so good or one of the related libraries already includes the definition of A, but if a library already owns the definition of A why putting `struct A;` ?

Comment: @Ken: that line is redundant since `typedef struct A A;` on its own defines two names for the type: `struct A` and `A`. The author might think that this fact about the syntax isn't clear, and preferred to define one new thing per line. It doesn't affect the fact that it's an incomplete type, though, and that the possible uses of incomplete types are limited. The reason that a name is needed at all is that otherwise `A* aName;` won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

I assume `struct A` is a forward declaration. It most likely is defined in one of the `.c`-files.

Doing so `struct A`'s members are private to the module defining it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of an opaque pointer, which is useful for passing handles.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer for some further info.   What may be interesting here from a C++ perspective, is the notion that you can define a class with a member that is a pointer to an (as yet) undefined `struct`.  Although this `struct` is thus not yet defined in the header, in some later cpp implementation this `struct` is given body, and the compiler does the rest.  This strategy is also called the Pimpl idiom (more of which you will find LOTS on the internet).  Microsoft discusses it briefly at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438477.aspx.